# POST ajax Completed 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, multipartform-data

I have runned in to a strange issue.
I wont to load an xml file and parse it via ajax, and append its contents to display on a page for further approval.

In view I have:

```
<%= form_tag import_path, multipart: true, remote: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "load" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
  respond_to :js
  def import
    respond_to do |format|
      parsing stuff ....
      @result = parsed_corrections

      format.js {render "import"}
    end
  end
```

Also I have import.js.erb view, with just alert for testing.
When I submit an empty form it works correct(content type is text/javascript), but if I submit an xml file it shows "Completed 406 Not Acceptable" content type is text/html.

I guess that issue is with content type.
jquery_rails and jquery_ujs are included in layout.

Thanks in advice for help.

Answer (score 0):

U need to handle xml format

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.html 
          format.xml  { parsing stuff.. }
        end
```

Comment: I need to submit an ajax post request.

Comment: Post request is sent according to your above description,but your not parsing your xml.

Comment: problem is that, when I send xml file content type is set to "text/html".

Comment: Specify the content type `:content_type => Mime::XML`